# Send push message from url to device GCM

Tags: php, android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I found a great code that sends push messages through the GCM.
The question is if it is possible to change the String "Google Cloud Messaging working well"

Address bar example I would write www.example.com/index.php?text=**work**

And the string will **work**.

Thanks

```
<?php
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyCJiVkatisdQ44rEM353PFGbia29mBVscA");
define("GOOGLE_GCM_URL", "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

function send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $message) {
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
        'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Problem occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}

$reg_id = "APA91bHuSGES.....nn5pWrrSz0dV63pg";
$msg = "Google Cloud Messaging working well";

send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`"Google Cloud Messaging working well";`

with

`$_GET['text'];`

to have a nicer code you would use

```
filter_input (INPUT_GET, 'text', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Thank you but how i need to write this in url?

Comment: No your url should be the one you placed 

www.example.com/index.php?text=Hello everyone :)

the $_GET function gets variables from the URL

Comment: Great :) mark it as answer but I must say you can use other page in html with from posting to this php file where you just create a input text field and post the only change would be $_POST['text'];

Comment: One more thing. 
One can ask you one more favor. 
Having the option to add more parameters. 
Example 
www.example.com/index.php?text=Hello&put1=its1&put2=work

Comment: using www.example.com/index.php?text=Hello&put1=its1&put2=work should be 
$text = $_GET['text'];
$put1 = $_GET['put1'];
$put2 = $_GET['put2'];